# "Find Windows" Shortcuts action hanging for a long time?

Tags: shortcuts-app

I'm trying to create a macOS shortcut (with the Shortcuts app) that opens a URL with Safari and then resizes the window. I'm finding that the shortcut hangs on "Find Windows" action for a good 13 seconds every time before moving onto the next action (Resize Window).

I've tried plenty of different settings for the Find Windows action, and they all seem to yield the same result. Has anyone else noticed this behavior or know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/viticci/status/1471957654796967937), the "Find Windows" action hanging for extended periods of time is a known bug that will be fixed in macOS Monterey 12.2.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).